Trim trailing NaN values in Python dataframe
Is there a way to trim trailing NaNs for each column in a dataframe?
Acquainted with dropna() and its parameters (eg, axis, how) for dealing with stuff like this but doesn't seem to address this case.
Sample data looks like this:
               1     2     3     4     5     6
2023-02-10   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00  0.00   NaN
2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.02  0.02   NaN
2023-02-14   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00  0.00   NaN
2023-02-15   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.01  0.01   NaN
2023-02-16   NaN   NaN   NaN -0.01 -0.01   NaN
2023-02-17   NaN   NaN   NaN -0.01 -0.01   NaN
2023-02-21   NaN   NaN   NaN -0.03 -0.03   NaN
2023-02-22   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00  0.00   NaN
2023-02-23   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00  0.00   NaN
2023-02-24   NaN -0.02   NaN -0.02 -0.02   NaN
2023-02-27   NaN  0.01   NaN  0.01  0.01   NaN
2023-02-28   NaN  0.03  0.03  0.00  0.00   NaN
2023-03-01   NaN -0.04 -0.04 -0.01 -0.01   NaN
2023-03-02   NaN  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00   NaN
2023-03-03   NaN -0.01 -0.01  0.04  0.04   NaN
2023-03-06   NaN -0.02 -0.02  0.02  0.02   NaN
2023-03-07 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01   NaN
2023-03-08 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01   NaN  0.01   NaN
2023-03-09  0.00 -0.02 -0.02   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-03-10 -0.03 -0.01 -0.01   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-03-13  0.02 -0.03 -0.03   NaN  0.01   NaN
2023-03-14 -0.02 -0.02 -0.02   NaN  0.01   NaN
2023-03-15 -0.04  0.00  0.00   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-03-16 -0.03  0.00  0.00   NaN  0.02   NaN
2023-03-17  0.01 -0.02 -0.02   NaN -0.01 -0.01
2023-03-20 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01   NaN  0.02  0.02
2023-03-21  0.03  0.01  0.01   NaN  0.01  0.01
2023-03-22  0.03 -0.05 -0.05   NaN -0.01 -0.01
2023-03-23 -0.01 -0.02 -0.02   NaN  0.01  0.01
2023-03-24  0.01  0.00  0.00   NaN  0.01  0.01

I'd like a result that looks like this:
               1     2     3     4     5     6
2023-02-10   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.02   NaN
2023-02-14   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-02-15   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.01   NaN
2023-02-16   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-02-17   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-02-21   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN -0.03   NaN
2023-02-22   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-02-23   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-02-24   NaN -0.02   NaN   NaN -0.02   NaN
2023-02-27   NaN  0.01   NaN   NaN  0.01   NaN
2023-02-28   NaN  0.03  0.03   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-03-01   NaN -0.04 -0.04   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-03-02   NaN  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00   NaN
2023-03-03   NaN -0.01 -0.01  0.02  0.04   NaN
2023-03-06   NaN -0.02 -0.02  0.00  0.02   NaN
2023-03-07 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01  0.01 -0.01   NaN
2023-03-08 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01  0.01   NaN
2023-03-09  0.00 -0.02 -0.02 -0.01 -0.01   NaN
2023-03-10 -0.03 -0.01 -0.01 -0.03 -0.01   NaN
2023-03-13  0.02 -0.03 -0.03  0.00  0.01   NaN
2023-03-14 -0.02 -0.02 -0.02  0.00  0.01   NaN
2023-03-15 -0.04  0.00  0.00 -0.02  0.00   NaN
2023-03-16 -0.03  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.02   NaN
2023-03-17  0.01 -0.02 -0.02  0.00 -0.01 -0.01
2023-03-20 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01  0.02  0.02
2023-03-21  0.03  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.01  0.01
2023-03-22  0.03 -0.05 -0.05  0.04 -0.01 -0.01
2023-03-23 -0.01 -0.02 -0.02  0.02  0.01  0.01
2023-03-24  0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.01  0.01


Could you elaborate more on this? It looks like you're doing more than trimming NaNs from some of the columns

@stefan_aus_hannover, just shifted fourth column down to end of rows.  Obviously need something as spaceholder since other columns have non-NaN entries, so filled in before with NaNs

Just for explicitness, should you have internal NaNs, they should remain?

@mozway, shouldn't happen, but say yes

@Chris I provided two options to handle this, if you never have internal NaNs trim_nans might be faster ;)

IIUC, you want to remove the trailing NaNs and "push" the Series to the bottom, ignoring the index. dropna won't be able to achieve this.
You should use a custom function:
def trim_last_nan(s):
    # identify rows that are not trailing NaNs
    m = s[::-1].notna().cummax()[::-1]
    # select them, reindex
    return s[m].set_axis(s.index[-m.sum():])

out = df.apply(trim_last_nan)

Or:
def trim_last_nan(s):
    # shift by the number of trailing NaNs
    return s.shift(s[::-1].isna().cummin().sum())

Output:
               1     2     3     4     5     6
2023-02-10   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.02   NaN
2023-02-14   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-02-15   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.01   NaN
2023-02-16   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-02-17   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-02-21   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN -0.03   NaN
2023-02-22   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-02-23   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-02-24   NaN -0.02   NaN   NaN -0.02   NaN
2023-02-27   NaN  0.01   NaN   NaN  0.01   NaN
2023-02-28   NaN  0.03  0.03   NaN  0.00   NaN
2023-03-01   NaN -0.04 -0.04   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-03-02   NaN  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00   NaN
2023-03-03   NaN -0.01 -0.01  0.02  0.04   NaN
2023-03-06   NaN -0.02 -0.02  0.00  0.02   NaN
2023-03-07 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01  0.01 -0.01   NaN
2023-03-08 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01  0.01   NaN
2023-03-09  0.00 -0.02 -0.02 -0.01 -0.01   NaN
2023-03-10 -0.03 -0.01 -0.01 -0.03 -0.01   NaN
2023-03-13  0.02 -0.03 -0.03  0.00  0.01   NaN
2023-03-14 -0.02 -0.02 -0.02  0.00  0.01   NaN
2023-03-15 -0.04  0.00  0.00 -0.02  0.00   NaN
2023-03-16 -0.03  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.02   NaN
2023-03-17  0.01 -0.02 -0.02  0.00 -0.01 -0.01
2023-03-20 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01  0.02  0.02
2023-03-21  0.03  0.01  0.01  0.00  0.01  0.01
2023-03-22  0.03 -0.05 -0.05  0.04 -0.01 -0.01
2023-03-23 -0.01 -0.02 -0.02  0.02  0.01  0.01
2023-03-24  0.01  0.00  0.00 -0.01  0.01  0.01

how the logic works
           input  notna      m   new_index
2023-03-17 -0.02   True   True  2023-03-21
2023-03-20   NaN  False   True  2023-03-22
2023-03-21  0.01   True   True  2023-03-23
2023-03-22 -0.05   True   True  2023-03-24
2023-03-23   NaN  False  False         NaN
2023-03-24   NaN  False  False         NaN

note on internal NaNs
If you have internal NaNs, those will remain.
For example:
# input
               1     2     3     4     5     6
2023-03-17   NaN -0.02 -0.02  0.00 -0.01 -0.01
2023-03-20   NaN   NaN -0.01 -0.01  0.02  0.02
2023-03-21  0.03  0.01   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2023-03-22  0.03 -0.05 -0.05   NaN -0.01 -0.01
2023-03-23 -0.01 -0.02 -0.02   NaN  0.01  0.01
2023-03-24  0.01   NaN  0.00   NaN  0.01   NaN

# output
               1     2     3     4     5     6
2023-03-17   NaN   NaN -0.02   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-03-20   NaN -0.02 -0.01   NaN  0.02 -0.01
2023-03-21  0.03   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.02
2023-03-22  0.03  0.01 -0.05   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-03-23 -0.01 -0.05 -0.02  0.00  0.01 -0.01
2023-03-24  0.01 -0.02  0.00 -0.01  0.01  0.01

If you want to push all values down, rather use:
def trim_nans(s):
    m = s.notna()
    return s[m].set_axis(s.index[-m.sum():])

out = df.apply(trim_nans)

Output:
               1     2     3     4     5     6
2023-03-20   NaN   NaN -0.02   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-03-21  0.03 -0.02 -0.01   NaN  0.02 -0.01
2023-03-22  0.03  0.01 -0.05   NaN -0.01  0.02
2023-03-23 -0.01 -0.05 -0.02  0.00  0.01 -0.01
2023-03-24  0.01 -0.02  0.00 -0.01  0.01  0.01

And if you want to avoid dropping the leading all-NaN row(s):
out = df.apply(trim_nans).reindex(df.index)

               1     2     3     4     5     6
2023-03-17   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2023-03-20   NaN   NaN -0.02   NaN -0.01   NaN
2023-03-21  0.03 -0.02 -0.01   NaN  0.02 -0.01
2023-03-22  0.03  0.01 -0.05   NaN -0.01  0.02
2023-03-23 -0.01 -0.05 -0.02  0.00  0.01 -0.01
2023-03-24  0.01 -0.02  0.00 -0.01  0.01  0.01

last valid value
If you only want the last valid value, ffill and slice with iloc:
df.ffill().iloc[[-1]]

               1    2    3     4     5     6
2023-03-24  0.01  0.0  0.0 -0.01  0.01  0.01


thanks for this...for my benefit, what did you do in including the data in your post to have it line up properly?

@Chris I'm using print(df.to_string()) to export it well aligned. I updated your question with a cleaner format

@mozway...potentially more straightforward--all I'm really looking to achieve by doing this is to pull the final 'valid' row.  is there a more direct way of doing that than all of this?

@Chris in this case just use df.ffill().iloc[[-1]] ;)
